# CodeIgniter Data insert is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In Codeigniter project ,when inserting multiple fields only one field value is not inserting in the database.

Controller Code For Billing

```
function billing()
{

    $arrInsert =array();
    $arrtoolsId =array();
    $this->db_session->unset_userdata('tools_cart');
    $arrtoolsId= $this->input->post('productId');
    foreach ($arrtoolsId as $val) {
    $arrToolrow = array();
    $productExclusivePrice =0;
    $arrToolrow =$this->product_model->getRow_products("gp.productId = '$val'");
    $price  =$arrToolrow['productPrice'];
    $actual_price=$this->input->post('actual_price');
    //$price    =$this->input->post('price');
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $qty=1;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $variant ='';
    $total  = ($price * trim($qty));
    $engineNo=$arrToolrow['engineNo'];
    $vehicleClass               =$arrToolrow['vehicleClass'];
        $manufacturer               =$arrToolrow['manufacturer'];
        $model                      =$arrToolrow['model'];
        //Note variant
        $variant                    = $arrToolrow['hp'];
        $vin                        = $arrToolrow['vin'];
        $wcoNo                      = $arrToolrow['wcoNo'];
        $horsePower                 =$arrToolrow['horsePower'];
        $fuel                       =$arrToolrow['fuel'];
        $noCylinders            =$arrToolrow['noCylinders'];
        $manufactureDate            =$arrToolrow['manufactureDate'];
        $seatCapacity               =$arrToolrow['seatCapacity'];
        $unladenWeight              =$arrToolrow['unladenWeight'];
        $frontAxle                  =$arrToolrow['frontAxle'];
        $rearAxle                   =$arrToolrow['rearAxle'];
        $otherAxle                  =$arrToolrow['otherAxle'];
        $tandemAxle             =$arrToolrow['tandemAxle'];
        $color                      =$arrToolrow['color'];
        $keyNo                      =$arrToolrow['keyNo'];
        $grossVehicleWeight     =$arrToolrow['grossVehicleWeight'];
        $typeofBody             =$arrToolrow['typeofBody'];

    $productExclusivePrice=$arrToolrow['productExclusivePrice'];
    $productTax =  $arrToolrow['productTax'];
    $saleExclusivePrice = ($productExclusivePrice * trim($qty));
    $saleTax    = ($arrToolrow['productTaxamt'] * trim($qty));
    $saleCess   = ($arrToolrow['productCess'] * trim($qty));
        $arrInsert[]    =array (
                "productId" =>$val,
                "engineNo"=>$engineNo,
                "productPrice"  =>round($price,2),
                "productTax"    =>$productTax,
                "saleQty"   =>$qty,
                "salePrice" =>round($total,2),
                "saleTax"=>round($saleTax,2),
                "saleCess"=>round($saleCess,2),
                "saleExclusiveprice"=>round($saleExclusivePrice,2),
                "added_date" =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                "vehicleClass"              =>$vehicleClass,
                "manufacturer"              =>$manufacturer,
                "model"                     =>$model,
                "variant"                   =>$variant,
                "vin"                       =>$vin,
                "wcoNo"                     =>$wcoNo,
                "horsePower"                =>$horsePower,
                "fuel"                      =>$fuel,
                "noCylinders"               =>$noCylinders,
                "manufactureDate"           =>$manufactureDate,
                "seatCapacity"              =>$seatCapacity,
                "unladenWeight"             =>$unladenWeight,
                "frontAxle"                 =>$frontAxle,
                "rearAxle"                  =>$rearAxle,
                "otherAxle"                 =>$otherAxle,
                "tandemAxle"                =>$tandemAxle,
                "color"                     =>$color,
                "keyNo"                     =>$keyNo,
                "grossVehicleWeight"        =>$grossVehicleWeight,
                "typeofBody"                =>$typeofBody
                );
    }
    $this->db_session->set_userdata('tools_cart',$arrInsert);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $data['list_product']= $this->db_session->userdata('tools_cart');
    $this->load->view('header_login');
    $this->load->view('catalog/billing',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer_login');
}
```

[image: Screenshot1]

Controller Code for Bill(After clicking bill button of the sale page)

```
function bill()
{

    if($this->db_session->userdata('tools_cart')) {
    $data['list_product']= $this->db_session->userdata('tools_cart');                                                                               
    }else{
        redirect('catalog/sale');
    }       
    $salePrice = $this->input->post('price'); 
    $actual_price=$this->input->post('actual_price');

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////CHANGE HERE
    $saleExclusiveprice = ($salePrice * 100) / 114.5;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////THIS CAN CHANGE EVERY YEAR            

    //$saleTax = $saleExclusiveprice *(14.5/100);

    //checking tax value with the current date...........
      $arrtax    = $this->tax_model->getTaxList(); 
        foreach($arrtax as $taxvalue) :       
          $currdate =$this->input->post('sale_date') ;       
          if(($taxvalue['fromdate']<=$currdate)&&($currdate<=$taxvalue['todate'])) 
          {
            // print_r($taxvalue['tax']); 
            $saleTax = $saleExclusiveprice *($taxvalue['tax']/100);
            $data['list_product'][0]['taxvalue'] = $taxvalue['tax'];                            
          }           
        endforeach;

    //$saleCess = $saleTax*(1/100);  //ORIGINALLY USED IN 2011
    $saleCess = 0;
    $data['list_product'][0]['salePrice'] = $salePrice;   
    $data['list_product'][0]['saleExclusiveprice'] = round($saleExclusiveprice,2);
    $data['list_product'][0]['saleTax'] = round($saleTax,2);
    $data['list_product'][0]['saleCess'] = round($saleCess,2);      
    $data['list_product'][0]['actual_price']=$this->input->post('actual_price');


        $scheme_id =serialize($arrtoolsId);
        $arrInsert  =array (
                "productId" =>$value['productId'],
                "saleCode"  =>$saleCode,
                "saleQty"   =>$value['saleQty'],
                "salePrice" => $value['salePrice'],
                "saleTax"   => $value['saleTax'],
                "saleCess"  => $value['saleCess'],
                "taxable_price" =>$taxable_price,
                "nontaxable_price" =>$nontaxable_price,
                "saleExclusiveprice"    => $value['saleExclusiveprice'],
                "saleCustomer"=>$saleCustomer,
                "saleUserId"=>$this->input->post('saleUserId'),
                "added_date" =>$date,
                "payType"=>$pay_type,
                "bank_id"=>$bank_id,
                "consultant_id"=>$consultant_id,
                "scheme_id"=>$scheme_id,
                "schemes_amount" => $total,
                "actual_price"  =>$actual_price

                );
        $saleId=0;
            if($this->product_model->insert_sale_entry($arrInsert)){
                    $saleId = $this->db->insert_id() ;
                    $arrStatus  =array (
                            "productSaleStatus" =>1
                                );
                $this->product_model->update_entry($arrStatus,$productId);
            }
    }
        $query  = $this->db->get_where('gm_users',array('userId'=>(int)$this->input->post('saleUserId')));
        if($query->num_rows >0) {
        $arrUser    =$query->row_array();
        }else{
            $arrUser    =array();     
        }   


    /*******************************************************************************/
    $this->db_session->unset_userdata('tools_cart');
    $data['arrtoolsId']     = $arrtoolsId;
    $data['saleCustomer']   =$saleCustomer;
    $data['saleCode']   =$saleCode;
    $data['saleId'] =$saleId;
    $data['saleDate']   =$date;
    $data['userinfo']   =$arrUser;
    $data['bank']       = $bank;
    $data['scheme']     = $schemeName;
    $data['wcoNo']      =$wcoNo;
    $data['actual_price'] =$actual_price;
    $this->load->view('header_login');
    $this->load->view('catalog/bill',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer_login');   
}
```

I have tried many ways, but its not working.I have hands on experience in Dot net mvc,but its my starting project in codeigniter.I want to know how the data flow works here and how to solve this?Is there any logical mistake i have done?

Model Code

```
 function insert_sale_entry($data)
{
   if($this->db->insert('gm_sale', $data)){
     return true;
   }
  return false;
}
```

The error field or the value field which is not inserting

```
$actual_price=$this->input->post('actual_price');
```

Comment: can you remove unrelated code and only show exact code

Comment: do the database related operation in model

Comment: @raheelshan i have deleted unrelated code from bill()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which field is not stored ? can you be more specific. The code appears to store one record at a time and there is only one value which is called from the post variable is what i believe is the problem. Will be able to help you if you can define what is not storing

Comment: $actual_price=$this->input->post('actual_price');

Comment: The above field ie,"actual_price" field is not getting updated.

Comment: Replace the variable definition with
$this->input->post('actual_price');

If this doesnt work, check if the value is stored in the product array that you have maintained.

Comment: hello Kunal Kinalekar,my actual value in the db was "0".But here my issue is that when i enter a value in the actual_price field it has to be inserted,but its not working for me.. what i have to do for this .?